# How to disable blur effect on Compiz, after it made my session completely black

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, compiz

I have been experimenting with *my effects* in **Compiz** (on Ubuntu 9.04).

I clicked the *blur effect*, everything that can move has turned black, therefore whenever I log on everything turns black.

I have managed to open a guest session blindly. But i wouldn't be able to do the same disabling it.

**Question:**

Is there a way to disable the blur effect I have set?

So far I have only found post [link text](https://serverfault.com/questions/33899/ubuntu-9-04-compiz) and nothing listed there seemed to work, perhaps the last comment might work, but I don't understand how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Log out.

On the login screen in the bottom left corner there is an `Options...` button.

Click it and then click `Select Session`
and choose `Failsafe GNOME`

Log in again and in the menu `System/Preferences/Compiz Config Settings Manager` remove the check mark from `Blur Windows`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to drop into failsafe mode to change Compiz settings.

Comment: @Scagnelli: No, but....um read the question.